# How to Enable HTTP Header Authorization for a WordPress Site

Tags: wordpress, http, header, authorization

I am trying to set up a new plugin to my wordpress site which requires the HTTP Header Authorization to be enabled. I tried to look in to the matter and looked around a bit but can't find any answer that solves my issue. I tried to use the below 2 lines of code individually inside my .htaccess file one at time to get this fixed but I still get the notification "HTTP Header Authorization is disabled". Can someone help me out, please?

Try 1:
RewriteEngine on
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

Try 2:
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

Comment: It's possibly just disabled for your domain on the server, contact your host to see if they can assist. This isn't a wordpress issue I do not believe.

Comment: Support is very slow on my hosting company. Is there anything that I can to fix this issue?

Comment: You could test the issue by setting up a copy of your site on your local host and see if the issue persists if so it’s definitely server related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanielVickers Thanks a lot. After I spoke with the Hosting Providers I figured that it's dissabled for Shared Hosting Environments.